# send mail using phpmailer yii2

Tags: php, email, yii2

I have installed zyx-phpmailer extension for send mail function in yii2 and working properly. But, when i checked via yii debugger the recipient is `empty`. If I using swiftmailer, there is no problem, but I must using zyx-phpmailer :(

code :

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                 ->setTo('people@blabla.com')
                 ->setFrom('admin@example.com')
                 ->setSubject('Test')
                 ->send();
```

Result (yii debugger) :

```
From    : admin@example.com
To      : empty // <- this is a problem
Subject : Test
Text body   (not set)
Successfully sent   : Yes
```

How to solve this issue? I'm still learning using yii2 framework.

Comment: As Ravenous said, try ->setTo(['people@blabla.com' => 'People Blabla']). The first one being the email address itself and the second one being the name.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your current mailer is actually the new extension and not SwiftMailer, you can trace it at runtime by calling this `Yii::trace(Yii::$app->get('mailer'))`. Maybe you did not fully configure it.

Try `->setTo(['people@blabla.com' => 'People Blabla'])`. The first one being the email address itself and the second one being the name.

Answer (score -1):

it work;try

```
Yii::$app->mail->compose()
     ->setFrom(['xx@xx.com' => 'My Example Site'])
     ->setTo([$form->email => $form->name])
     ->setSubject($form->subject)
     ->setTextBody($form->text)
     ->send();
```

Comment: He said there's no problem when he uses SwiftMailer but he MUST use PHPMailer.